# Why is my bar plot showing an empty output?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I am trying to create a simple bar plot but the output is empty (picture attached) for some reason.

```
#test graph
test1 <- ggplot(leg19.votosglobais, aes(partido, votos), geom_bar(stat = "identity"))
```

The dataset is this:

```
> leg19.votosglobais
   partido   votos
1       ps 1908036
2      psd 1457704
3       be  500017
4  pcp-pev  332473
5   cds-pp  221774
6      pan  174511
7       ch   67826
8       il   67681
9        l   57172
10       a   40487
11  outros  167727
12 brancos  131704
13   nulos  123882
```

Any suggestions for how to fix this please?

[test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ulip8.png)

Comment: May be you need `stat = 'identity'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues - 1) `stat` would be "identity", 2), the `aes` is not closed and `geom_bar` is another layer

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(leg19.votosglobais, aes(partido, votos)) + 
        geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
leg19.votosglobais <- structure(list(partido = c("ps", "psd", "be", "pcp-pev", "cds-pp", 
"pan", "ch", "il", "l", "a", "outros", "brancos", "nulos"), votos = c(1908036L, 
1457704L, 500017L, 332473L, 221774L, 174511L, 67826L, 67681L, 
57172L, 40487L, 167727L, 131704L, 123882L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"
))
```

Comment: Simple solution - thanks!! Beginner mistake :)